# Delete files getting names from array without knowing extension

Tags: php, unlink

I have an array which contains a number of file names **without extensions** (below, the numbers are the name of the files):

```
[1] => 214
[2] => 12
[3] => 2763
[4] => 356
[5] => 87
```

I would like to delete these files from the server without knowing their extensions (which could be .jpg .JPG .GIF .jpeg, etc).

I tried using GLOB but I don't understand how to teach PHP to use wildcards and in the same time get the name of the files from the array.

Comment: Can you show code you've attempted?

Comment: Obvious, but if you have a 3 files with the same name but different extensions, you'd be removing them all.

Comment: File names correspond to unique IDs of a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$names` is your array:

```
$path = "../pictures/";
foreach ($names as $name) {
  foreach (glob($path . $name . '*') as $filename) {
    unlink(realpath($filename));
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but $filename is empty. My array is called $orphans, print_r($orphans) confirm it has data. I chaged your $names to $orphans but $filename is empty.

Comment: The script I posted assumes that files you are going to remove are at the same directory as your PHP-script. If not you should add path to the directory (`foreach($PATH.glob($name.'*') as $filename)`).

Comment: Sorry still empty. Don't know why. Script is in /php, file to be deleted are in /pictures. I added path: `foreach("../pictures/".glob($name."*") as $filename)` and then `unlink("../pictures/".$filename)` but it does not work.

Comment: @Nicero Sorry, it was silly typo in my comment. I have updated post with correct code using path.